# Multiple video in android app

Tags: android

I am looking the way to play multiple rtsp-streams in my android app. RTSP-streams doesn't shows when I am trying to create multiple videoviews (it shows only one stream, other streams is stopped). Can anybody help me with it?
Thanks in advance.